# Trigger.io Directory Management

Tags: trigger.io

Just starting out with the Trigger.io workflow. Was wondering if anybody could enlighten me as to the deal with different projects in different directories. I've inadvertently created another test application through my local Trigger Toolkit via the terminal, and have noted (after some searching) that it has created a new app project deep within my ~/Library/Trigger Toolkit/ directory. The original app I created (via the web interface) was plonked in /Users/[Name]/[Name of App].

When I forge run/build it runs the local version deep within the Trigger \Toolkit directory, not the version within my Users directory. How can I register this one with my local build? And destroy the test created with the local build.

If you know what the hell I'm trying to get at then you deserve a stack overflow crown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you've managed to get an app appearing in `~/Library/Trigger Toolkit`. This overview might help:

The folder structure for a forge app is something like:

```
my-app/
  local_config.json
  src/
    config.json
    identity.json
    index.html
```

The `forge` commandline program tries to treat the current working directory as an app (i.e. it expects you to run it in a folder like `my-app` above).

The exception is `forge create` which sets up this structure. For example if you ran `forge create` in `/Users/tim/my-app` then it would set up something like the above.

The Trigger Toolkit has two actions for dealing with these sorts of folders - create and import. The create action sets up an app structure like the above, the import action allows to import the `my-app` folder above into the list of apps available to work on in the Toolkit.

You can remove an app from the list by using the "forget" button next to the app in the list. If you want to "destroy" an app it always comes down to just deleting a folder, in this case I'd delete the `my-app` folder.

The folder `~/Library/Trigger Toolkit` contains the code for the Trigger Toolkit itself, as well as a file which keeps track of the apps listed in the Toolkit. The only way I can see that you'd get an app appearing in this folder is to manually `cd` to it and use `forge create`.

To summarise, each app is isolated to a folder. When using the commandline tools you just need to use e.g. `forge build android` and `forge run android` in the specific folder for that app. If using the Toolkit you need to import the folder or have created it through the Toolkit, clicking that app in the app list puts you in the context of it, and run/package actions from there will run using the folder registered for that app.

Comment: You're right. I must have manually cd'd to the directory itself. Have manually deleted the files now - and as I created it locally it never appeared on my online Trigger.io. Lo and behold, I have another question regarding TriggerIO you might be interested in. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028020/what-is-the-purpose-of-data-role-in-triggerio